# No Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in Apple dev center

Tags: ios, certificate

I have a problem to create p12 file in Apple Development center. Option for "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" is not visible on my account. I tried on different browsers and machines.

[image]

Comment: Did you buy a developer account?

Comment: What you mean by developer account ? I have account above is print scr from my account. I need to be a member of the program and pay $99 to have access to certificates ?

Comment: Yes you need to buy a developer account.